# How can I use bootstrap columns as variables?

Tags: php, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to hide Bootstrap columns. But how will the columns next to it evenly share the remaining space?

```
<button id="firstB">first</button>
<button id="secondB">second</button>
<button id="thirdB">third</button>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div id="first" class="col-sm-2">
      first column x2
    </div>
    <div id="second" class="col-sm-6">
      second column x6
    </div>
    <div id="third" class="col-sm-4">
      Third column x4
    </div>
  </div>
</div>



.container{
  width:100%;
  height:100px;
  background-color:red;
}
.row div{
  background-color:aqua;
}

$( "#firstB" ).click(function() {
  $( "#first" ).toggle();
});

$( "#secondB" ).click(function() {
  $( "#second" ).toggle();
});

$( "#thirdB" ).click(function() {
  $( "#third" ).toggle();
});
```

https://codepen.io/suleymantasci/pen/eYBeqOR

For example if I hide the first column, how do I share the remaining space proportionally or evenly?

Can variable values ​​be given with php or js?
for example: col-sm - {$ a-b}

note: initially column widths are different as in the example.

Comment: Initial values can be set through variables by PHP. Any further changes would have to be done through JS (because that's how you hide elements). You can do whatever calculations you need to inside your click handlers and then modify the classList of the remaining divs.

Comment: @El_Vanja Could you show me an example if I ask? I did not work with php before.

Comment: Go through a tutorial about basics. It all boils down to printing variable values inside your HTML, nothing complicated. Plus, the logic of your page is unknown. I don't know how you determine the width to begin with.